# Laravel 5 attach with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, pivot

I have this laravel code in my controller detach function.

```
$input = Input::all();
    $product= Products::findOrFail($input['product_id']);
    $product->tags()->detach($input['tag_id']);
    $product= Products::where('customer_id', Auth::user()->customers_id)->get();

    return view('products.tagsdelete', [
            'products' => $product,
        ]);
```

This works fine, it deletes the tag realation from my pivot table. The only thing that bugs me it that I don't want to reload the page everytime I press the delete button on my view.

( Of course I could make a selection of all tags the user want to delete, but I want to to this live with Ajax )

My problem is, I couldn't find anything that helps me with detachment from laravel + Ajax. I'm quite okay with Javascript and Jquery but Ajax is still a new thing for me..

So can anybody help me there? I'm really stuck.

Thanks for taking your time :)

@Wiriya Rungruang

current controller code:

```
public function detach()
    {
    $input = Input::all();
    $product= Products::findOrFail($input['product_id']);
    $product->tags()->detach($input['tag_id']);
    $product= Products::where('customer_id', Auth::user()->customers_id)->get();
}
```

my button:

```
<button type="submit" class="delete-tag-btn" data-product_id="{{ $product->id }}" data-tag_id="{{ $tag->id }}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
```

at the bottom of the code the JS:

```
   <script>
    $(".delete-tag-btn").on('click', function(){
        var url = "{{ route('detach') }}"; // Url to deleteTag function
        url += "product_id=" + $(this).data('product_id');
        url += "&tag_id=" + $(this).data('tag_id');

        // Now url should look like this 'http://localhost/deletetag?product_id=2&tag_id=5
        // Send get request with url to your server
        $.get(url, function(response){
            alert("success");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** : You should create function detach tag from product in your controller and return status success or failure(or nothing)

**In your controller**

```
function detachTag(){
    $input = Input::all();
    $product= Products::findOrFail($input['product_id']);
    $product->tags()->detach($input['tag_id']);
    $product= Products::where('customer_id', Auth::user()->customers_id)->get();

    return "Some state for checking it a success or not";
}
```

**Second** : Create javascript function for checking when you click on delete button send request with parameter to function that we created in the first step and rerender or remove that tag from your HTML page
**Parameter is mean product_id and tag_id that your want to detach it

**In your js**

```
$(".delete-tag-btn").on('click', function(){
    var url = "localhost/deletetag?"; // Url to deleteTag function
    url += "product_id=" + $(this).data('product_id');
    url += "&tag_id=" + $(this).data('tag_id');

    // Now url should look like this 'http://localhost/deletetag?product_id=2&tag_id=5
    // Send get request with url to your server
    $.get(url, function(response){
        // Do what you want
    });
});
```

So when you click on **.delete-tag-btn** It will send request for detach it

Comment: I will give it a try, give me some minutes :)

Comment: I have a little problem with your second step. I haven't did something like a click event that sends data to my controller and something like rerender/remove with JS is something new for me

Comment: you delete button should look like this `<div class="delete-tag-btn" data-product_id="2" data-tag_id="1">Delete</div>` You can push product_id and tag_id to button when you render it in **view**. you can read about **Jquery Data** in here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: yes, I know how I can create a button and pass data through them.. I was a little bit confused of another of your sentences -- but it was more my mistake, sorry

Comment: and about rerender/remove I think if you delete that tag then that tag should remove from your HTML you can do it in many ways such as remove element, edit your HTML element

Comment: I will update my question, please have a look at it in about 2 minutes :)

Comment: sorry, took me a little longer.. Well, I don't think javascript will find the index "product_id" and "tag_id".. cause I doesn't know how I can define them as a index for their variables..

Comment: I see you code everything look good but I'm not sure Laravel can create function without `return`  can you try to put it to your function and let me know what is the problems for now. This is how that javascript works https://jsfiddle.net/jLf2fcba/

Comment: well I tried it but just nothing gets returned.. no error message in the console and nothing from laravel. I klick the button and nothing happens

Comment: Are you check that tags are already detach or not? Nothing happened because we don't do anything with HTML when we click. We just send request to server for detach it only.

Comment: Yes I checked it but still.. I think I will do it with checkboxes if I can't figure it out with Ajax

Comment: Are you sure that **click function** is work? Try to put some console.log in click funtion and .get for make sure everything work.

Comment: the click function work, I'm getting a string if I'm pressing the button..

Answer (score 0):

While you can right a simple ajax call, send data and return html and replace it with the old html

lets begin :)

first step is to write ajax, and send it when form is submit or any button is clicked (as per your code)

this one is sample ajax, just fill in your data in it.

```
var BASEURL = window.location.origin + "/your_domain_name/";
    $.ajax({
                    url: BASEURL + "your_route",
                    type: "POST/GET", //any_one
                    data: {
                         // Your data comes here (object)
                    },
                    beforeSend: function () {

                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response); // your html in return
                    },
                    complete: function (response) {

                    }
                });
```

now a call will be send with your data to controller respective to specified route you mentioned, processing will be normal.
It will return only html. You can do whatever you want with this html.

One important problem you might face if considering these instructions is, right now the view you are returning is probably of whole page (because the page is been refresh every time), but if you are thinking to replace it with new html, your will only have to return that part of the page may be a single row or something like that. So break your view in many sub views. Php `@include(//path)` (blade) might come handy. Thats how I use to work. :)

Comment: I will give it a try, give me some minutes :)